# Can I get European-wide traffic predictions similar to the one from Paris?

Tags: europe, online-resources, traffic

Already in 2004 there exists a really [neat online service](http://www.infotrafic.com/route.php?region=IDF) that not only gave traffic information but also the chance of getting into a traffic jam. (see screendump below).

[image: Traffic jams in Paris]

I really liked this information since it gives you some indication on when it is best to drive in and around Paris. 10 years later the [IDF website](http://www.infotrafic.com/route.php?region=IDF#), still exist but I find it hard to find the same information for other regions in Europe. It would be so convenient to have this information for for Example the Benelux and Germany to plan ahead when going on a road-trip.

Am I not searching enough or does these visualizations of traffic information for other regions simply not exist?

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/), find the city for which you want to find historical traffic information
2. Click on Satellite, then on Traffic
3. Click on "change" next to "Live Traffic"
4. Slide the time bar to the desired time and day of the week.

This feature works in all major cities worldwide.

Comment: I don't think clicking on *Satellite* is necessary.